# Does systemd make dig/nslookup useless?

Tags: systemd, dns

I'm trying to debug some issues on dns resolving and was trying `nslookup` (now deprecated) and `dig`.

I am, however, on a system that uses `systemd` for configuring `/etc/resolv.conf`.

```
~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

This seems to render `dig` useless because all it does is point to the dns server at `127.0.0.53` which is a systemd construct on my machine.

```
~$ dig www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31247
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     54  IN  A   216.58.212.164

;; Query time: 29 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sun Jun 18 10:45:49 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59
```

Is this a true claim? If you're on systemd everything else is out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, for (at least) two reasons:

1. systemd-resolved is an optional component of systemd. It need not be in use on a machine running systemd.
2. dig has a lot of options that make it useful even with systemd-resolved (or any other local DNS cache, like dnsmasq) running. For example, you can specify the nameserver to query: `dig @8.8.8.8 google.com.` or any number of other options useful to debug DNS.